# Extracted files not recognized

Tags: tar, 7-zip, extract

I extracted a tar.gz file with 7-Zip.

It worked fine, all the files and folders are now visible and have names, different size and so on, yet I cannot open them.

And the icons are all the same - a white piece of paper.

For example, when I try to open the file INSTALL it asks me with which program to open it, instead of launching the installation.

I tried to rename it .msi .exe and so on, but that didn't work (probably because all the other necessary files aren't accessible as well.)

Comment: Based on your mention of 7-Zip, I'm going to guess you are using Windows. What operating system was the software contained in the .tar.gz designed for?

Comment: Probably ubuntu, since it is GNU chess. Although last time it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: The fact that it they are all "paper" icons means that windows has no knowledge of the extensions in use. For example, `INSTALL` has no extension. If you'd rename this to INSTALL.txt, you'd be able to double click and open it in notepad (or whatever is associated with .txt files on your system.)

Comment: I think INSTALL is a simple text file containing instructions

Comment: Note, that there's a chance that notepad is going to barf when it sees unix linebreaks and/or unicode. Textpad handles both of those.

Comment: Almost certainly, what you've downloaded is the source tarball instead of the compiled game installer.

Comment: GNU chess for Windows can be found at http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/chess.htm

Comment: @Jason Aller yes, but it is the old version. And INSTALL is just a text file, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extracting a [tarball](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_%28computing%29) (`.tar.gz`) on a Windows system will have varying results depending on the content of the tarball.

If the contents were designed to work on a Windows system there will be no problems.

If the contents were intended for another operating system Windows will not be able to automatically work with them. Options at this vary based on what the tarball held. For instance, If it was software you may be able to compile it with an appropriate compiler.